# Objects in isometric tile games using XNA and Tiled

Tags: c#, xna, tiles, isometric, tiled

Since a few days ago that I'm trying to make a game using XNA. I'm using tiles for my game and I've decided to make it look isometrical. I've seen tutorials that explain how to do a game engine using matrices for the position of the tiles but since it's so much work to do it that way I decided to use Tiled for making my maps so much easier and graphical.

I've made my map 30x30 tiles and each tile has 64x32, also I've put objects underneath each element where I don't want the character to walk but when I see the XML file made by Tiled, each object has it's coords acording the edges of the map and no the left and upper sides of the window.

I've already tried to transform those coords passing them to orthogonal coords or even trying to rotate the objects but with any successful result.

I don't know if there is some way of fixing this or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I'd be pleased if someone could give me a solution to fix those coords or some indications to make an isometrical tiled game, because I've seen that some people say that it's too easy but I find it harder as I thought.

Any help will be well appreciated.

Comment: Example please :) Seriously, I have no idea what you are asking. Some sample input/output and perhaps the code you are using would be greatly beneficial in figuring it out.

Comment: I've tried to insert images into the question but I can't due to my reputation. It's very difficult to explain with images.

Comment: How about some numbers? ASCII art? There has to be some way you can provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest that you research the model, view and projection matrices. 
XNA matrices API has a lot of useful and easy to use functionality but it seems as though you need to understand the fundamentals first.

Perhaps it may help to think of it in the reverse, translating your camera (50, 0) is the same as not translating the camera and instead translating everything in your world (-50, 0).

It is also possible that tiled and XNA have different coordinate systems (I have no idea). In which case its possible that you are viewing the back of your tiles. XNA doesn't implicitly render both sides of a polygon (google back face culling).

You can read stuff here: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/ if you dont like the math, read the rest anyway.